# Dynamic theme using url Param

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, cookies, themes

I have one requirement. Can you anybody suggest the possible ways to achieve it.

I want to change the theme of my application based on the URL passed in every routes.I am using the below technologies.
- Frontend : Angular JS
- Backend  : Node.js

eg: localhost/x/about
    localhost/y/about

I achieved these via cookies by passing the param using localtion.search at the time of login. But I need that theme param in all the routes.Based on that theme need to change.Can anyone suggest the possible ways.

## app.js

```
app = angular.module('themeApp', ['ngRoute'])  
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
 .when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 .when('/:id/about',{
    templateUrl: 'about.html'
 })
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
});
app.controller('themeController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {  
 console.log($routeParams.id);
 // set the default theme   
 $scope.css = $routeParams.id;
});
```

### menu.html (it is not complete, confuse here. please correct, how to call)

```
 <li>
   <a href="about">About</a>

 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="home">Home</a>

 </li>
```

### index.html

```
 <html ng-app="themeApp" ng-controller="themeController">  
 <head>  
  <!-- pull in css based on angular -->  
 <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="css/{{css}}.css">   
 </head>  
 <body>  
 <div ng-view></div>
    <!-- bring in JS and angular -->  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.14/angular.js">        </script>
    <script rc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"> </script> 
  </body>  
  </html>
```

### css/

```
it contains the three files,
- red.css

body{  
  background-color: red;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;  
  font-size: 15px; 
}
```

- green.css
   body{
    background-color: green;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px; 
   }

  - blue.css
    body{
    background-color: blue;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px; 
    }

Answer (score 0):

The quick and simple answer would be to use $rootScope. $rootScope is available to all controllers, but like all global variables should be used sparingly.

Here's a good post explaining $rootScope. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/UVDE100914-Understanding-AngularJS-$rootScope-and-$scope.html

Basically if you're using it on your two controllers for pages x and y

```
app.controller('login',['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.foo='bar';
}]);

app.controller('xCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.lorem=$rootScope.foo;
    console.log($scope.lorem); //bar
}]);

app.controller('yCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.ipsum=$rootScope.foo;
    console.log($scope.ipsum); //bar
}]);
```

Can then use them in your HTML markup as normal.

Using $rootScope is much simpler, but if you wanted to use the router to pull down the id each time, it is also possible.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
     .when('/',{
        controller: 'indexController',
        templateUrl: 'view/index.html'
     })
     .when('/:id/about',{
        controller: 'xCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'view/x.html'
     })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('xCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.foo=$routeParams.id;
}]);
```

If you have a lot more pages than just /about I could imagine this getting a bit tricky with the routing.

You could even couple it with root scope then pass it around to your other controllers.

```
app.controller('xCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','$routeParams', function($scope,$rootScope,$routeParams){
    $rootScope.foo=$routeParams.id;
    $scope.lorem=$rootScope.foo;
}]);
```

--EDIT based on comment--
I might need some code to be sure of what you're after, but perhaps this clarifies?

URL: mysite.com/blue/about

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
     .when('/',{
        controller: 'indexController',
        templateUrl: 'view/index.html'
     })
     .when('/:id/about',{
        controller: 'xCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'view/x.html'
     })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('xCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.theme=$routeParams.id;
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="xCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{{theme}}">
        My theme is {{theme}}.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blue
{
    background-color: blue;
}
.green
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: this is answer suitable for the changing templates via rootscope.As my requirement is user has to see the theme info in url as well as css file changes accordingly.

Comment: this has only one css with several classes. I want to manage multiple css files for each theme and that url should be same for all navigations in application.  eg: localhost/x/about , localhost/x/contact and localhost/y/about , localhost/y/contact. If user types any of url, i have to change css file either x / y

Comment: Try using if statements in your controller to set additional variables for classses if you need them.

Comment: How the query param keep as it, in all routes/ pages

Comment: If you have all of your routes behind id it will continue to work. /:id/about or /:id/lorem/ipsum or /:id/x/y/z will be able to take the id param from $routeParams

Comment: Depends on how you generate your URLs. If your URL is mysite.com/purple/foo/bar/foobar your $routeParams.id will be 'purple'.

Comment: this is just exp, app = angular.module('themeApp', ['ngRoute'])  
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
     .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
     })
     .when('/:id/about',{
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
     })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
app.controller('themeController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {  
 console.log($routeParams.id);
    // set the default theme   
    $scope.css = $routeParams.id;
});

Comment: <html ng-app="themeApp" ng-controller="themeController">  
<head>  
    <!-- pull in css based on angular -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="css/{{css}}.css">   
</head>  
  
<body>  
        <div ng-view></div>
        <!-- bring in JS and angular -->  
        <script src="../../scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../../scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"> </script> 
</body>  
</html>

Comment: and i have three css files separately

Comment: and also one menu file to navigate, home and about

Comment: here, i am confusing, how to pass in href, if i have 3 different themes

Comment: Can you please look into it and correct me logic, if anything wrong

Comment: For reference, please edit the question with the new code. I'll update the answer with the code.

Comment: the example i understood.But how here, I am not interest to hardcode the theme value in user click. I need it as dynamic

Comment: <a href="#/{{css}}/about">About</a>, I need like this, but here the css as undefined